# 3DES-DUKPT (CBC) decryption confirmation

Tags: encryption, tripledes, dukpt

I have `Key Serial Number (KSN)`, `Base Derivation Key (BDK)`, and encrypted string.

```
KSN = 9500030000044520002B
BDK = 0123456789ABCDEFFEDCBA9876543210
```

Encrypted string

```
23F87C010DCD08E0211D509F3310B1A63564D44134A512AA0740CA2A0FD81BF045AF70395C537774680B566548C2966DFD7F575CC756408A89BCF12A93B8873114FF6EFC69014EA0E0A4EBD392EF40A3F1E15012B3D613E18E4CFD4DE3AFCD771D8B2CE8AB54B1CB7671F24F8562262AAA603C45BF87DE33407234927D7CDA28C86CE29E05A9D03ED65EB3D5DDD3C15A61A79AB8CB7481828339A0B099EDC3BBE3A1C416A06E965FF3CAF2CC395E691AB86C325183EF3A245A3DDF53CBD6D6AEFD0769F560165E4B5C99EBA2584AD3EC
```

The decryption from the Device Manufacturer Menu is supposed to be:

Right answer

```
FC8200C6F28200C282027C008E1200000000000000004201410342035E031F005F24031912315F25039507019F0607A00000000310109F0702FFC09F0D0500000000009F0E0500000000009F0F0500000000009F100706010A039600009F2608738091EC178FF5709F2701409F36020017950508001410009B02E8009C01009F3303E0F8C89F34034203009F370450577DCF9F40057000B0B001DFDF70050000000000DFDF71050000000000DFDF7205000000000057134761739981010014D19122010123456789012F000000000000
```

My decryption turned out to be:

```
E4771F740C1B1D45DFA193A1DF73C80B3CF68F625DB4604A4C5C392B72BDC98236FAA09D32D674A45D7C3AFAA08E26DAD0B3ABC14662F9D386B9C2F7B992EC35BD7B765450C9E8E56D5D1CEAAE0641E5CB66D2102C58A6325C845E62BBB8994E0441AF1887CDD0C3C0AD2A8AD178A949C0944D46A04DA08DAE30FA571CE4C0EACE4AAFC503708AD0240584C80506F98F0C8D8E348F0A5B0E949EED814C8F1C2B9157B66455715685673D0F1B816AD4AEF7743EB9E339361A733F1EF37CA1DC5D468CA988DDD9E74E7CCC9F999FDBBCFE
```

and session key turned out to be:

```
7ED0EDD8A1961ABF7CFC995219B80FC57ED0EDD8A1961ABF
```

Can any decryption professional run a little 3DES-DUKPT and check it for me?

The instruction from the Device manufacturer claims that `3DES-DUKPT is formed, using Data Skye variant and (KSN)" for the encrypted value.`

THank you!

Comment: We're can't help if you don't show your code.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [BP-Tools](https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/products/babylon-payments-tools-bp-tools) freeware to check your results.

It contains a DUKPT calculator.